# Como fazer um array de objetos ter apenas valores únicos?

Tags: php, coleção

Se eu tenho uma coleção com o mesmo objeto em um `array`, como eu poderia fazer para tornar essa coleção com apenas objetos de instâncias únicas?

Exemplo:

```
$a = new stdClass;

$a->id = 1;

$b = $a; // mesmo objeto

$c = new stdClass;

$c->id = 2;


$colecao = [];

$colecao[] = $a;
$colecao[] = $b;
$colecao[] = $c;
```

Quero retornar apenas os objetos que não sejam o mesmo (porque `$a` nesse caso tem o mesmo hash (id interno no php) de `$b`).

Se eu tentar fazer isso, eu terei um erro:

```
$unicos = array_unique($colecao);
```

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Parece que `array_unique` só serve para valores do tipo `scalar`.

Como poderia fazer com que o resultado acima fosse semelhante abaixo?

```
[$a, $c]
```

Comment: Já posso prever respostas com `spl_object_hash` e `SplObjectStorage` :) :) :) :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agradeço a todos pelas respostas, mas, nesse caso, vou dar minha resposta, para prestar alguns esclarecimentos.

## Como funcionam os objetos no PHP?

Primeiro, vamos reforçar alguns termos:

> Objeto é uma instância de uma classe.

Segundo, vamos esclarecer algo: no PHP, eu posso ter duas instâncias de `stdClass` (`$a` e `$b`), porém se eu igualar `$c` a `$a`, os dois serão o mesmo objeto trabalhando na mesma instância (o que é alterado em `$c` implica em alteração em `$a`).

Ou seja:

`$a`, `$b` e `$c` são instâncias de `stdClass`, porém `$c` e `$a` é o mesmo objeto, já que `$c` faz referência a `$a` - no php os objetos atribuidos são automaticamente passados por referência, de acordo com o manual.

Suponhamos o seguinte cenário:

```
$a = new stdClass;

$b = new stdClass;

$c = $a;
```

Isso:

```
[$a, $b, $c]
```

Seria a mesma coisa que isso:

```
[$a, $b, $a]
```

Pois para `$c` se tornar uma nova instância de `stdClass`, independente da instância guardada em `$a`, teriamos que usar a palavra chave `clone`.

Assim:

```
$c = clone $a
```

## SplObjectStorage - A Solução

Então, para retornar um array de objetos com instâncias únicas (instâncias do mesmo objeto, porém não repetindo esses objetos), poderiamos fazer assim:

```
$a = new stdClass;

$a->id = 1;

$b = $a;

$b->id = 2;

$c = new stdClass;

$c->id = 3;

$storage = new SplObjectStorage();

$storage->attach($a);
$storage->attach($b);
$storage->attach($c);

print_r(iterator_to_array($storage));
```

O resultado seria:

```
Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
        )

    [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 3
        )

)
```

Notem que o `id` que era 1, passou a ser `2`.

Para entenderem o que eu digo, veja o que ocorre nesse exemplo:

```
$a = new stdClass;

$a->id = 1;

$b = $a;

$b->id = 2;

var_dump($a->id, $b->id); // int 2 e int 2
```

http://3v4l.org/nCG4J

## Porque isso aconteceu?

Porque, internamente, o `SplObjectStorage`, utiliza o hash do objeto como a índice para atribuí-lo a um `array`.
Isso é feito através de uma função chamada `spl_object_hash`:

Veja esse exemplo:

```
var_dump(spl_object_hash($a));
var_dump(spl_object_hash($b));
var_dump(spl_object_hash($c));

var_dump(spl_object_hash($a) === spl_object_hash($b));

var_dump(spl_object_hash($a) === spl_object_hash($c));

var_dump(spl_object_hash($b) === spl_object_hash($c));
```

O resultado é:

```
string '0000000076e70b6400007fac140b77fd' (length=32)

string '0000000076e70b6400007fac140b77fd' (length=32)

string '0000000076e70b6500007fac140b77fd' (length=32)

boolean true

boolean false

boolean false
```

Isso deixa claro que `$c` e `$a`, são os mesmos.
Deixo então aí minha pequena contribuição. Obrigado pelas respostas!

## Por que não array_unique?

Porque ele não usa a mesma regra de "unicidade" que o `SplObjectStorage` usa.

Veja esse exemplo:

```
$a = new stdClass;

$a->id = 2;

$b = new stdClass;

$b->id = 2;

$case1 = array_unique([$a, $b], SORT_REGULAR);

$storage = new SplObjectStorage();

$storage->attach($a);
$storage->attach($b);

$case2 = iterator_to_array($storage);


var_dump($case1, $case2);
```

Veja os resultados:

```
#array_unique
   array (size=1)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'id' => int 2
#SplObjectStorage com iterator_to_array
    array (size=2)
      0 => 
        object(stdClass)[6]
          public 'id' => int 2
      1 => 
        object(stdClass)[7]
          public 'id' => int 2
```

Exemplo: http://3v4l.org/hQKL5

Parece que o `array_unique` levou em consideração o fato de `id` ter o mesmo valor nos dois casos, porém, como dito anteriormente, `SplObjectStorage` levou em consideração a identificação interna do objeto.

Se eu estiver errado em alguma coisa, podem me corrigir :). Mas é o que entendo por objetos no PHP!

Answer (score 5):

Experimenta assim:

```
$unicos = array_unique($colecao, SORT_REGULAR);
```

A função [array_unique()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php) recebe como argumentos dois parâmetros (o segundo parâmetro é opcional):

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

> **array**: O array que pretendes ordenar.
>
> **sort_flags**: este parâmetro é opcional mas é importante pois permite alterar o comportamento por defeito da função. Ele pode assumir um dos seguintes valores:
>
> - SORT_REGULAR - comparação "normal" (sem alteração de tipos)
> - SORT_NUMERIC - comparação numérica
> - SORT_STRING - compara os items como strings **(opção por defeito)**
> - SORT_LOCALE_STRING - compara os items como strings (dependente do LOCALE)

Por defeito, a função irá tentar converter os objectos para string para efectuar a comparação, daí veres a mensagem:

> Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string

Podes verificar em acção aqui: http://3v4l.org/3O810

Comment: Quase isso, porém ele removeu as "instâncias diferentes". Você sabe que o PHP considera automaticamente passado por referência uma atribuição da instância a um objeto. Logo, deveria retornar 2 elementos, e não 1.  Mas dei +1 pois a resposta foi interessante (só carece de explicações)

Comment: E o manual do php em português não fala nada que o `array_unique` aceita um segundo parâmetro, porém funcionou aqui no meu teste!

Comment: Incluí na resposta um "fiddle". Parece estar a funcionar pois retorna dois elementos. Podes verificar?

Comment: Isso porque os objetos têm valores diferentes. Mas, se eu tivesse duas instâncias do mesmo objeto, eu teria problemas se elas tivessem os mesmos valores. Veja a resposta que eu dei e entenderá o que eu quis dizer com "coleção de objetos da mesma instância, porém instâncias unicas - excluíndo referências"

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza a resposta do @bruno é melhor, mas como já fiz irei postar assim mesmo, para didática.

Poderias criar uma função:

```
function ClearArray($arr, $KeepKey = FALSE){
    if (!is_array($arr)) return FALSE; // Se não for array retorna FALSE
    if (count($arr) == 0) return $arr; // Se estiver vazio retorna-o
    $narr = Array(); // Array de Retorno
    $c = 0; // Novos indices
    foreach($arr as $k => $v){
        // Se mantém o índice original usa-o senão usa o novo
        $k = ($KeepKey ? $k : $c);          
        $keep = TRUE; // Mantém o item

        foreach($narr as $k2 => $v2){ // Percorre o novo array
            // Verifica se já foi adicionado um item igual
            if ($v === $v2){
                $keep = FALSE; // Não mantém o registro
                break;
            }

        }

        if($keep){ // Se mantém o item
            $narr[$k] = $v; // Adiciona-o no novo array
            $c++;
        }

    }

    return $narr; // Retorna
}
```

Uso:

```
$a = new stdClass;
$a->id = 1;

$b = $a; // mesmo objeto

$c = new stdClass;
$c->id = 2;

$colecao = Array();

$colecao[] = $a;
$colecao[] = $b;
$colecao[] = $c;

// Array Original
var_dump($colecao);

// Array com itens unicos
$arr = ClearArray($colecao, true);

echo '-------------------------'.PHP_EOL;

var_dump($arr);
$unicos = array_unique($colecao, SORT_REGULAR);
```

Saída:

```
array(3) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [1]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
-------------------------
array(2) {
  [0]=>
  object(stdClass)#1 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(1)
  }
  [2]=>
  object(stdClass)#2 (1) {
    ["id"]=>
    int(2)
  }
}
```