# Remover elementos duplicados em Array

Tags: php, json, array

Estou recebendo um array por `JSON`, e usando o `array_unique` para remover valores duplicados, porém, está exibindo o seguinte erro: `<b>Notice</b>:  Array to string conversion in <b>/var/www/html/.... </b> on line <b>10</b><br />"`

Na linha 10 está justamente o `array_unique`.

Tentei de várias maneiras, porém não consigo remover estes valores duplicados.

Alguem pode me ajudar??

Obs: os dados enviados por JSON estão sendo recebidos corretamente.

```
$dados = json_decode(($_POST['dados']));
$dados_arr = array_unique($dados); //linha 10
print_r($dados_arr);
```

Comment: O erro esta informando que você esta tentando fazer uma string virar um array;
tente da seguinte maneira: `$dados_arr[] = $dados` e depois tente passar o `array_unique`

Comment: Coloca a estrutura do json.

Comment: Tentei alterar como o Rafaek citou, porém continuo com os mesmos resultados. Segue parte da estrutura:
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 29/12/1988
                    [2] => S
                )

            [1] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 4
                    [1] => 29/12/1988
                    [2] => S
                )

            [2] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 7
                    [1] => 
                    [2] => N
                )

Comment: Veja minha resposta. Fiz o teste na linha de comando e foi exatamente o seu erro que ocorreu quando não usei o `SORT_REGULAR`!

Comment: @ThiagoAlessandro, só mais um detalhe adicional que não vou adicionar na resposta: Você deveria utilizar o segundo parâmetro do `json_decode` como `true`, para garantir que te será retornado um `array`, ao invés de um `stdClass(object)`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O Manual do PHP não detalha isso na versão portuguesa da função `array_unique`, porém na versão inglêsa, ela mostra que esta função tem um segundo parâmetro.

Veja o "esqueleto" dessa função - retirado do [Manual do PHP, array_unique,  em Inglês](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
array array_unique ( array $array [, int $sort_flags = SORT_STRING ] )
```

A função `array_unique` utiliza internamente um método de comparação, que por padrão os valores são tratados como `strings`, e por isso é gerado o erro.

Então você tem que mudar essa forma de comparação. Ao invés de `SORT_STRING` vamos utilizar `SORT_REGULAR`.

Exemplo:

```
$dados = json_decode(($_POST['dados']));
$dados_arr = array_unique($dados, SORT_REGULAR); //linha 10
print_r($dados_arr);
```

Ao acresentar a constante `SORT_REGULAR` no segundo parâmetro de `array_unique`, é possível trabalhar com outros valores, independente do tipo do mesmo.

Podemos até mesmo utilizar o `SORT_REGULAR` para [fazer uma coleção de objetos únicos](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76395/como-fazer-um-array-de-objetos-ter-apenas-valores-%C3%BAnicos).

Para você ter mais informações, veja as possíveis flags que podem ser utilizadas com `array_unique`.

- `SORT_REGULAR` - compara os itens normalmente (não muda os tipos)
- `SORT_NUMERIC` - compara itens numéricamente
- `SORT_STRING`  - compara os itens como strings
- `SORT_LOCALE_STRING` - compara os itens como strings, baseado na localização atual.

Comment: Achei que o problema era um array multidimensional, +1;

Comment: @rray, aprendi isso ao fazer as "perguntas que já sabia a resposta". O cara respondeu isso aqui http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/76395/como-fazer-um-array-de-objetos-ter-apenas-valores-%C3%BAnicos